# Remove all characters of a string after the fourth space

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Im looking for a way to remove the fourth space, (and everything following it) from a string ,this function to be for every line list from "input text area"

**Example:** if i have a list "Vertically" in Input text area( i will use here days of the week just for example:

```
Monday February 8 2016 08:05:07 GMT-0700 (PDT)
Tuesday February 9 2016 09:07:07 GMT-0700 (PDT)
Wednesday February 10 2016 01:04:07 GMT-0700 (PDT)
Thursday February 11 2016 05:15:07 GMT-0700 (PDT)
etc
```

when i click button remove ,results in Output Textarea to be "Vertically" like this:

```
Monday February 8 2016
Tuesday February 9 2016
Wednesday February 10 2016
Thursday February 11 2016
```

i  used this script, its work good for 1st line ,but just for first line ,i want to work for all lines. Please help me ,im trying to maked myself searching in stackoverflow but without succes ,pleas can somone modify my script or tell me what i maked wrong, thank you so much.

**this is my script**:

```
function remove_list() {
  var count = 0;
  var list = document.myForm.Input.value;
  list = list.replace(/^((?:[^ ]* ){3}[^ ]*) [\S\s]*/, "$1");

  var listvalues = new Array();
  var newlist = new Array();

  listvalues = list.split(/[\s,]+/).join("");

  var hash = new Object();

  for (var i = 0; i < listvalues.length; i++) {
    if (hash[listvalues[i].toLowerCase()] != 0) {
      newlist = newlist.concat(listvalues[i]);
      hash[listvalues[i].toLowerCase()] = 1
    } else {
      count++;
    }
  }
  document.myForm.Output.value = newlist.join("");

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression *almost* works.

If you want it to work for multiple lines, you could use the [`m` multi-line flag](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) so that the anchors `^`/`$` match the start/end of each line rather than the start/end of the string.

Here is your revised regular expression:

```
/^((?:[^ ]* ){3}[^ ]*) [\S\s]*?$/gm
```

However, you could actually simplify it to the following:

```
/^((?:\S+\s+){3}\S+).*$/gm
```

Usage:

```
textarea.value.replace(/^((?:\S+\s+){3}\S+).*$/gm, '$1');
```

**Explanation:**

- `gm` - Global flag; multi-line flag
- `^` - Anchor asserting the start of each line
- `((?:\S+\s+){3}\S+)` - Capturing group to match one or more non-whitespace chracters followed by one or more whitespace characters three times; then match one or more non-whitespace characters again until the forth whitespace character
- `.*` - Match the remaining characters on the line
- `$` - Anchor asserting the end of each line.

Here is an example demonstrating this:

```js
var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
var replacedValue = textarea.value.replace(/^((?:\S+\s+){3}\S+).*$/gm, '$1');

document.getElementById('output').textContent = replacedValue;
```

```html
<textarea>
Monday February 8 2016 08:05:07 GMT-0700 (PDT)
Tuesday February 9 2016 09:07:07 GMT-0700 (PDT)
Wednesday February 10 2016 01:04:07 GMT-0700 (PDT)
Thursday February 11 2016 05:15:07 GMT-0700 (PDT)
</textarea>

<p>Output:</p>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: Or just `/^((\S+\s+){3}\S+).*/gm`.

Comment: @Vidul I didn't use any positive lookaheads; there aren't any above... `(?:)` is a non-capturing group. If I use the expression you just posted, there would be two capturing groups, which is unnecessary. I'd prefer to keep it at a single capturing group to avoid any possible confusion.

Comment: @Vidul See https://regex101.com/r/tO4oH2/1 vs https://regex101.com/r/yZ0sZ3/1 and compare the capturing groups. Of course I could use either of them, but like I said, I'd prefer to keep it at a single capturing group to avoid any possible confusion.

Comment: My oversight (the comment was corrected). The beginning `^` and the end `$` in your example are also completely unnecessary. It could be just `/((?:\S+\s+){3}\S+).*/gm`.

Comment: @Josh Crozier  thank you milion times i realy apreciate your help thank you so much.

Comment: i try to give vote up but its say i dont have reputation :( but  thank you so much.

Comment: @JoshCrozier  if i have a list with slash
Monday/February/8/2016/08:05:07/GMT-0700/(PDT)
Tuesday/February/9/2016/09:07:07/GMT-0700/(PDT)
Wednesday/February/10/2016/01:04:07/GMT-0700 (PDT)
Thursday/February/11/2016/05:15:07/GMT-0700 (PDT)

when i click button remove ,results in Output Textarea to be "Vertically" like this

Monday/February/8/2016
Tuesday/February/9/2016
Wednesday/February/10/2016
Thursday/February/11/2016


pleas can you modify your code for this second problem when i have /  thank you so much

textarea.value.replace(/^((?:\S+\s+){3}\S+).*$/gm, '$1');

Comment: can you help me pleas to modify your code if i have list with slash / textarea.value.replace(/^((?:\S+\s+){3}\S+).*$/gm, '$1');

Answer (score 1):

You are making that way more complicated with regex than you need to. All you really need to do is split the whole thing on new lines, loop through those, split on spaces, and then rejoin a spliced version.

```
function removeExtra() {
    var ta = document.getElementById('lines'),
    lines = ta.innerHTML,
    reformatted = [];

  lines = lines.split("\n");
  for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
    var parts = lines[i].split(" ");
    reformatted.push( parts.splice(0, 4).join(" ") );
  }

  ta.innerHTML = reformatted.join("\n");

}
```

full fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/w7z88vjv/

Comment: @AronDuby thank you and from you for your help thank so much , thank you.i woul dlike to give vote up but the stackoverflow say i dont have 15 reputaton ,thank you so much.